# Click Drop Down Menu for Responsive layout

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I am refining a responsive navigation menu, and would like to have the menu icon clicked to have the drop down menu instead of the hover effect. I am using a Google jquery so I am not sure if that is all ready scripted in the script src or not, and would I have to create the drop down menu manually in jquery or just an easy CSS or html5 fix. Thanks for any feedback.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Dan Meier Website</title>

<meta name="description" content="Responsive Header Nav">

<meta name="author" content="Treehouse">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="layoutnew.css">

<!--[if IE]> <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->


</head>

<body>

<header>

<a href="#" id="logo"></a>

<nav>

<a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>

<ul>

<li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

</ul>

</nav>

</header>

CSS

header {

    background: #404040;
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #4C9CF1;
    z-index: 100;

}

#logo{

    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background: img src="images/menuicon.png" no-repeat center;
    display: block;

}

nav {

    float: right;
    padding: 20px;  

}

#nav ul.sub-nav {
    display: none;
}

#nav ul.visible {
    display: block;
}
ul {

    list-style: none;

}

li {

    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px

}

/*MEDIA QUERY*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 640px) {

    header {

        position: absolute;

    }

    #menu-icon {

        display:inline-block;

    }

    nav ul, nav:active ul { 

        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #fff;
        border: 5px solid #444;
        right: 20px;
        top: 60px;
        width: 50%;
        border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;

    }

    nav li {

        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin: 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS to style and hide your menu and do the following:

Load jQuery (I can't see that in your code)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

And you can do something like this (to show and hide the menu on click)

```
$('#menu-icon').click( function(){
   $('nav ul').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Ok,perhaps I am linking my .js file wrong, here is my header...<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Dan Meier Website</title>

<meta name="description" content="Responsive Header Nav">

<meta name="author" content="Treehouse">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="layoutnew.css">

<!--[if IE]> <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dropdownmenu.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: Got it! added it to the end of the nav element instead of before...rookie mistake. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, so new question, same topic. The click function works, but when I re-size the window back to full screen the menu-icon only goes back to the menu text tabs if the drop down menu is present, so when its just the menu-icon it does not show text when re-sized to bigger screen...

Comment: I am not sure how you design your app, normally you would have a standard design for desktop screen and use @media query to target smaller screen and with this, you will be able to create different styling for the menu based on the screen size. So on smaller screens, you will see the #menu-icon and you are able to toggle it and on desktop, your menu will be normal without that icon. If you are still a beginner, I suggest looking at http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(window).resize(function(){  
        var w = $(window).width();  
        if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {  
            menu.removeAttr('style');  
        }  
    });
```

Where "menu" is the variable value of your menu. you can declare it like.....

```
 $(function() {  
            var menu        = $('ul li');
});
```

hope it will help you..... :D
Rj